# Is it allowed to change code in windows form designer generated code (*.Designer.cs files) in order to make some controls static?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to make some controls static, for example:

```
private static System.Windows.Forms.TextBox infoBox;
infoBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
```

so I will able to use it in other class:

```
string myInfo = CourseWork.Form1.infoBox.Text;
```

But when I use visual designer, visual studio changes my code to:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox infoBox; // it removes static
this.infoBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox(); // and add .this
```

And then I've got next error:

```
    An object reference is required for the non-static field, 
method, or property 'CourseWork.Form1.infobox'
```

Is it possible to avoid this ? or maybe I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: The auto-generated code is the designer's resposibility. You must not touch it. Use subclassing or something if you need to extend it or write the interface manually

Comment: Even if you *could* do this, you absolutely *shouldn't*. You shouldn't even have *access* to the field in a different class, and if you want to access a textbox within a form, you should have an *instance* of the form with which to work.

Comment: I think if you explained *why* you are trying to convert a textbox definition to `static` we might be able to point you in the right direction.  Primarily because what you are currently doing is very very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the design is flawed. The infoBox belongs to the form, so objects outside the form should not be trying to access it.

It sounds like you need to add an accessor method to your form class, something like `GetText()`, to provide visibility to your other objects without breaking the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 0):

Dont.....do......it!

Expose the controls with a method, I would even suggest exposing a change in a control property with an Invoke driven method, that way if a change is called cross-thread, it will be properly handled.

Example:

```
public delegate void SetButtonTextDelegate(string text);
public void SetButtonText(String text)
{
     if(button.InvokeRequired)
     {
         Callback settext = new SetButtonTextDelegate(SetButtonText);
         button.Invoke(settext, text);
     }
     else
     {
         button.Text = text;
     }
}
```

Then in any external class, just call the SetButtonText("new text"); method

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there will be at most one instance of the form, you could create a static property exposing the text box's text. In order to do this, you need a static reference to the form itself (I call the form `InfoForm`, its more informative than `Form1`).

For this purpose I add a static `Open` method. If the form is open alredy it brings it to foreground, otherwise it opens it and assigns it to the static field `_instance`.

```
public partial class InfoForm : Form
{
    public InfoForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static InfoForm _instance;

    public static InfoForm Open()
    {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new InfoForm();
            _instance.Show();
        } else {
            _instance.BringToFront();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);

        // Make sure _instance is null when form is closed
        _instance = null;
    }

    // Exposes the text of the infoBox
    public static string InfoText
    {
        get { return _instance == null ? null : _instance.infoBox.Text; }
        set { if (_instance != null) _instance.infoBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Now you can open the form and access its `infoText` `TextBox` like this

```
InfoForm.Open();
InfoForm.InfoText = "Hello";
string msg = InfoForm.InfoText;
```